# Is it possible to exclude the email signatures when searching in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, email-signature

Currently I'm trying to search through my rather large email archive on Gmail.

Unfortunately the words I like to find also occur in almost any email footer as the signature text.

While I understand that there is no entity type "signature" in a plain email body, it seems that Gmail is still (limited) capable of detecting signatures (and collapsing them with those <kbd>...</kbd> buttons).

**My question:**

Is there a search operator to tell Gmail to search for text but omit the signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda, there is a work around to do what you want, while doing the search, you can specify that results should not have some text, by using the field `Doesn't have`, and include in this field some text from the signatures.

or if you can also specify to search for whole sentences only, by using double quotes like this:

`"my one long sentence"`

so it will match the whole sentence only, and not single words.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, since virtually _all_ emails have the signature, this would actually omit all search results.